# simple way to return 2 or more rows using a SELECT in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to figure out the most simple way to return 2 or more rows using a select statement in pl/sql to the sqlplus output.  Here is a basic example.

```
begin
  select sysdate,'12345' xid from dual
    union all
  select sysdate,'67890' xid from dual;
end;
/
```

Error is "an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: "most simple way to return 2 or more rows" to what? what do you want the two or more rows to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a cursor to return the result of a query:

```
SQL> VARIABLE x REFCURSOR
SQL> BEGIN
  2     OPEN :x FOR SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> PRINT x

    ROWNUM
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can return a ResultSet from a PL/SQL. Take a look at [this URL](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/return_result_set.html).

Answer (score 0):

When writing a SQL code in a BEGIN-END block, you cannot display its result-set in the editor. Trim the BEGIN-END from your query, and it would happily display the results.

Basically, code within a BEGIN-END block is not used for displaying results, it is used for data processing instead. So you should simply write:

```
SELECT SYSDATE,'12345' XID FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE,'67890' FROM DUAL;
```

to display the result-set in your SQL editor.

Also notice that I removed alias "XID" in second SELECT statement: you need to give column aliases in only first query in a UNION/UNION ALL statement.